# Put a symbol before and after each character in a string

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I would like to add brackets to each character in a string. So

```
"HelloWorld"
```

should become:

```
"[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]"
```

I have used this code:

```
word = "HelloWorld"
newWord = ""
for letter in word:
    newWord += "[%s]" % letter
```

which is the most straightforward  way to do it but the string concatenations are pretty slow.
Any suggestions on speeding up this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> s = "HelloWorld"
>>> ''.join('[{}]'.format(x) for x in s)
'[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]'
```

If string is huge then using `str.join` with a list comprehension will be faster and memory efficient than using a generator expression(https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/846892):

```
>>> ''.join(['[{}]'.format(x) for x in s])
'[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]'
```

---

From [Python performance tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation):

**Avoid this:**

```
s = ""
for substring in list:
    s += substring
```

Use `s = "".join(list)` instead. The former is a very common and catastrophic mistake when building large strings.

Comment: how can I check whether this is faster than the other code?

Comment: `timeit`, but it almost certainly is because yours creates n new string objects.

Comment: @MehdiNellen Read this https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#String_Concatenation, and time using `timeit` module.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: If speed is a concern, offloading the iteration to the underline native code might have some performance benefit at least in CPython.

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way would probably be with a generator comprehension:

```
>>> s = "HelloWorld"
>>> "".join("[%s]" % c for c in s)
'[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]'
```

Ashwini Chaudhary's answer is very similar, but uses the modern (Python3) string format function. The old string interpolation with `%` still works fine and is a bit simpler.

A bit more creatively, inserting `][` between each character, and surrounding it all with `[]`. I *guess* this might be a bit faster, since it doesn't do as many string interpolations, but speed shouldn't be an issue here.

```
>>> "[" + "][".join(s) + "]"
'[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]'
```

Comment: looks great, I've used this code, although haven't checked whether it is the fastest one. :)

Comment: @MehdiNellen: Without knowing more about your code, I guess the difference in speed shouldn't matter much. Go for the cleanest version, or the one you understand best. If it turns out to be a bottleneck, you can still optimize afterwards.

Comment: >>> timeit.timeit("''.join('[%s]' % c for c in 'lol')", number=100000)
0.36499309539794922
>>> timeit.timeit('"[" + "][".join("lol") + "]"', number=100000)
0.1732938289642334

Comment: Your second option is the first one I thought of, except I would use format: `"[{}]".format(']['.join(s))`

Comment: FWIW, if you want to save a few microseconds, `python timeit.py` on my system says `"".join("[%s]" % c for c in s)` is 4.7μs, `"["+"][".join(s)+"]"` is 1.41μs per loop (and my alternative using format is 1.8μs). YMMV

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about speed and need a fast implementation, try to determine an implementation which offloads the iteration to the underline native module. This is true for at least in CPython.

**Suggested Implementation**

```
"[{}]".format(']['.join(s))
```

**Output**

```
'[H][e][l][l][o][W][o][r][l][d]'
```

**Comparing with a competing solution**

```
In [12]: s = "a" * 10000

In [13]: %timeit "[{}]".format(']['.join(s))
1000 loops, best of 3: 215 us per loop

In [14]: %timeit ''.join(['[{}]'.format(x) for x in s])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.06 ms per loop

In [15]: %timeit ''.join('[{}]'.format(x) for x in s)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.26 ms per loop
```