# How add "." before each letter in string

Tags: python

as title says i simply need to add a . before each letter in my string
while having vowels removed and making it lowercase 
i got it working just cant add the .s there
here is my code

```
s = str(input())
vowels = ('a','e','o','u','i','A','E','O','U','I')
for letter in s:
    if letter in vowels:
        s = s.replace(letter,'').replace()
print(s)
```

Comment: Hint: use a regex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put a symbol before and after each character in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554740/put-a-symbol-before-and-after-each-character-in-a-string)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hint: don't use a regexp ;-) (you don't need it)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers: well the nice thing about regexes (given these are well implemented) is that these use dynamic programming, and thus can convert an *O(m n)* approach, into an *O(m+n)* approach :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it step by step:

Replace all the vowels in the string with ''

```
for i in s:
    for j in vowels:
        s=s.replace(j,'')
```

Convert the string into lowercase:

```
s=s.lower()
```

Adding '.' in between each letters:

```
s='.' + '.'.join(s)
```

Comment: Does not work for the first letter. OP needs a dot before every letter if I read the title correctly.

Comment: Edited it for the first letter :)

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
s = input()
vowels = set('aeoui')

print(''.join([f'.{x}' for x in s.lower() if x not in vowels]))
```

**Sample run**:

```
Hello
.h.l.l
```

Comment: Simpler: `print('.'.join(x for x in s if x not in vowels))`

Answer (score 1):

All other answers will insert a `.` in front of every **character** in the string, but you specified that you want **letters** only. So I am assuming that you only want `a-z` to be prepended with a `.` for which I suggest `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "This is some test string. It contains some symbols also ()!!"
result = re.sub('[aeoui]', '', s.lower())  # remove vowels and make lowercase
result = re.sub("([a-z])", r".\1", result)  # prepend '.' to every letter
print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
.t.h.s .s .s.m .t.s.t .s.t.r.n.g. .t .c.n.t.n.s .s.m .s.y.m.b.l.s .l.s ()!!
```